# While using GET method, can I convert query string to Object and send to an endpoint?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using Axios for HTTP request and using useState hook for query string value.

```js
const url = `${BASE_URL}/courses?page=${currentPage}&count=${contentCount}&lastContentId=${lastContentId}&search=${searchVal}`

axios.get(url)
.then((res) => console.log(res))
```

For now, I send every query string inside `url` variable. However, what I'm trying to do is:

```js
    const url = `${BASE_URL}/courses?`
    const queryObj: any = {
      page: currentPage,
      count: contentCount,
      lastContentId : lastContentId,
      search: searchVal,
    }
    axios
      .get(url, queryObj)
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
```

convert into this format. However, it is not working.

What I want to know is whether it is possible or not to convert query string to object and how it can be done.

Comment: Do you want to send an object to server? how about converting your object to base64 and send it like `baseurl?obj=...` and then decode it in backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the [docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config)

Second argument of `get` is `options` which have multiple parameters `params` included

```
const queryObj: any = {
  page: currentPage,
  count: contentCount,
  lastContentId : lastContentId,
  search: searchVal,
}
axios
  .get(url, { params: queryObj })
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you pass query parameters seems wrong according to [this tutorial](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/get-query-params). Also, if you haven't taken a look at the [axios api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axios-api) in npm, I highly recommend that.

Comment: Yeap. I'll make sure to read the docs. Thank you.